# UITabBarController to load subviews

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I am kind of stuck and would appreciate any ideas on what I did wrong.
I created programmatically a NSObject which holds a UITabBarController to which three ViewControllers are added:

```
UITabBarController tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

ControllerOne = [[OneViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OneView" bundle:nil];     
ControllerTwo = [[TwoViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TwoView" bundle:nil];   
ControllerThree = [[ThreeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThreeView" bundle:nil];  
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
[viewControllers addObject:ControllerOne];
[viewControllers addObject:ControllerTwo];
[viewControllers addObject:ControllerThree];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];'
```

I now display the tabBarController's view

```
 viewController.modalTransitionStyle = transitionStyle;
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

with viewController being the just created tabBarController.
The view changes fine, displaying the tabbar correctly (Icons and titles) but fails to show e.g. OneViewController's view. I assume that the view is not loaded since the `- (void)viewDidLoad` is not being called for any of the subview controllers.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks,
equi

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your nib names are how you have typed them? It's not called OneViewController.xib?, for example?

Comment: The nib names are OneView.xib, TwoView.xib and ThreeView.xib. As far as I am aware I do not need to provide the file ending when using 'initWithNibName'. But I just tried it with the _.xib_ file extension and it did not load as well.

Comment: I have tried what you are trying to do with no problems. So maybe you can post more of your code such as ControllerOne and all of your ivar and property declarations.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted out the issue.
The above code actually worked, reason for the view not appearing was that I accidentally synthesised 'view' in the UIViewController derivative.